# Sum of one column in DataTable depending on value in other column ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, sum

I'm trying to make sum of one column, but I need to do it depending on the other column.
Here's the story: I'm having values of 8 combination of blood groups in first column (A+, A-, B+, B-, O+, O-, AB+, AB-) and the amounts of donated blood in second column.
What I want to do is to make sum for each blood type.

Here is a current data table:
[image]

So I need to get integer values: 850 in some abMinus, 400 in bPlus, 500 in oMinus, ... and 0 in  oPlus and aMinus variables, according to that picture.

The data source for my data table is SQL database and I use this query to fill the table:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select bloodGroup, bloodAmount from Donacije ", connection);
                SqlCommandBuilder dcb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                DataTable bloodBalanceTable = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(bloodBalanceTable);
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

From database table called 'Donacije' I get values of bloodGroup and bloodAmount.

Somebody maybe have a suggestion on what is the best and easiest way to do this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq-To-DataSet:

```
var bloodGroupAmounts = bloodBalanceTable.AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BloodGoup"))
   .Select(grp => new { BloodGroup = grp.Key, Amount = grp.Sum(r => Field<int>("BloodAmount")) });
```

This selects anonymous types with two properties. You could also create a dictionary with the group as key and the amount per group as value:

```
var bloodGroupAmounts = bloodBalanceTable.AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BloodGoup"))
   .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Sum(r => Field<int>("BloodAmount")));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering on my question. :) I will learn more about LINQ as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LINQ expression, with `GroupBy()` and `Sum()`. But it's necessary to know the data source for your table to give an exact code to solve this problem.

Now that you've update your question to show that the table DataSource is a `DataTable`, I'll show you the exact code with some explanations.

Using simple "LINQ to Objects", which require `using System.Linq`, you can do this:

```
 List<GroupQty> qtyByGroups = GroupQty.SampleDataTable
  .Select() // This returns an array of DataRow
  .GroupBy(dr => dr["BloodGroup"].ToString()) // This groups by BloodGroup column
  .Select(g => new GroupQty  // Use anonymous type, or the GroupQty class below
  {
    BloodGroup = g.Key, // The key by which you ordered: BloodGroup
    Qty = g.Sum(dr => (int) dr["Qty"])  // Sum of the datarows in that group
  })
  .ToList();
```

This solution doesn't require anything but LINQ, and you use the syntax you're used to.

You can define a class like this to get a typed result:

```
public class GroupQty
{
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to use the result as a data source for a table, or work with a typed result.

The solution by Tim Schmelter requires to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly in your project. If you don't add this reference, it will not work. This solution doesn't require any additional reference, and the syntax is what you use everyday (apart from the LINQ to objects part).

For learning LINQ I recommend you seeing this: [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), which shows nearly all you can do with LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've added new info in post about data source. Don't know if I have to provide more information on it? :)

Comment: Either use @JotaBe suggested method or alter your sql query to `select bloodGroup, sum(bloodAmount) as bloodAmount from Donacije group by 1`

Comment: @B0Andrew that totally worked, thank you for suggestion. I will have to learn more about both ADO.NET and LINQ for sure! :)